# Netbeans 7.2.1. Java Application with Embedded Derby Database

Tags: java, database, netbeans, derby

I pretend to build a java application with a derby database embedded. However, I can't establish a connection with my database. After following some tutorials I found on Internet, I ended up adding this code to my main method.

```
String dbms = "jdbc:derby:database;create=true";
String uName = "admin";
String uPass= "pass";

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbms, uName, uPass);
```

But I get the following error: `"No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby...."`
Strange is that if I use a not embedded connection like this:

```
String dbms = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/database";
```

The connection works. Am i missing some file on libraries or something, in a tutorial i found it was saying to add the "derbyclient.jar" to the libraries of the project, but still not working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the embedded version of Derby then the `derbyclient.jar` isn't enough. You'll need to include the full `derby.jar` library.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code.
Yo have to create a class with any name example conexionDB, and into the class put the next code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 *
 * @author programmerhn
 */
public class ConexionDB {

    private Connection con;

    /**
     *
     */
    public void Conectar()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/accounts", "username", "password");
             System.out.println("Connection successfully");

        }catch(  ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
    }

}
```